# How to get a button inside the asp form without reloading the page?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

So I have this update panel and it is working well.

```
    <div>
        <button id="foo" onclick="changeVal(this.id);">Send the ID "foo"...</button>
    </div>

<form runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" >
</asp:ScriptManager> 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always"> 
<ContentTemplate> 

<div id="thethetext">
<asp:Literal ID="thetext" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>

</ContentTemplate> 
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="myButton" EventName="Click"/>
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>



   **<!-- MOVE BUTTON (ID="foo") OVER HERE TO DISPLAY IT UNDER THE LITERAL -->**

<asp:HiddenField ID="blah" runat="server" value="Initial Value"></asp:HiddenField>
<asp:Button ID="myButton" Text="Get Concatenated..." OnClick="Test" runat="server"></asp:Button>    
</form>
```

However, I want to move the button (with id "foo") inside the asp form. so it displays under the Literal user control... but if I do that, everytime I clicked on it, it reloads the page. Is there anyway to avoid that? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reloads the page because your button submits the form that you have just placed it in.
Give your button the attribute `type` with value `button` so it won't submit:

```
<div>
 <button type="button" id="foo" onclick="changeVal(this.id);">Send the ID "foo"...</button>
</div>
```

Reference: [W3C HTML 4.01 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5)

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I also found out that adding "return false" to the onclick function makes it work too.

Comment: @eastboundr, perhaps that might work as well, but then a browser without javascript could still accidently submit the form by pressing the button. `type="button"` prevents also that. :)